# How to get binding data back from Hyperlink click event inside a Gridview column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

My question is how can I get binding data from other column using a hyperlink click event?

I have a GridView and It shows data from my custom class.The GridView contains 4 columns and one of them has the hyperlink.

XML :

```
<ListView Name="CCYVIEW">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Authors">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="CurrencyName" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CurrencyName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="CurrencyTitle" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CurrencyTitle}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="BaseCurrency" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BaseCurrency}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="170">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                     <Hyperlink Foreground="#FFF7CA00" Click="Hyperlink_Click"> Add to market watch</Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Now what I want is when I click the hyperlink from the third or fourth column. It should give me all the datas from the third or fourth column (CurrencyName,Currencytitle etc).

Comment: In your List View Bind `SelectedItem` to a property from your `ViewModel`.

Comment: I've done that in the code behind. And all three columns are showing data as I bonded them. But I want to retrieve those data when I click the hyperlink in a certain column.

Comment: `SelectedItem` will hold **ALL** the data for every column.

Answer (score 0):

First let's reference ViewModel in your View:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"//you will need to adapt this to the structure of your project.
```

Now set it as a `DataContext` either:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Or:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

In your xaml you should have the list view defined like so:

```
<ListView Name="CCYVIEW" SelectedItem="{Binding NameOfTheVMProperty}">
```

Then in your view model you should have a property like this:

```
private object _selectedItem;

public object SelectedItem //because you haven't specified the type I am using an object here
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}
```

At this point you have the item selected in your ViewModel, so let's go to the event handler:

```
private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
    vm.SelectedItem;//this is where you now have access to the selected item
}
```

Now there is a chance that you may not have the item selected so you could just find the parent of the clicked element as a `ListViewItem` and then get the `DataContext` of that.